# split address into column in sql/oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

kindly help me in splitting address into crew_name, City, person_name,owner_name. i want columns till owner name only.

Example Address:-

```
1) ESS GEE ELECTRO/SOLUTIONS PVT. LT /  noida / BIJENDRA SINGH / . / 9999077027 / 784261 / 2000027697
2) / delhi / BIJENDRA SINGH / NAKI RAM / 9891884813 / 784262 / 2000057282
3) ELECTRO PVT. LT/  punjab / w/o birbal SINGH /  / 9310202020 / 784270 / 2000080264
```

we can use `'/  '` to split.

there can also empty crew name or city name (like example 2 and example 3- owner_name) so in that case we will show empty column in result.

Comment: How should you split the string like `ELECTRO PVT. LT/  w / o punjab / w/o birbal SINGH`, where slash is inside a value, but it can be identified only by human's eye?

Answer (score 0):

I will admit that handling separators that are more than one character is tricky.  So, my simplest recommendation is to replace the separate with something like `'|'` or `'^'` that is a single character.

That makes this pretty simple:

```
select x.*,
       replace(regexp_substr(replace(address, '/ ', '|'), '[^|]*[|]', 1, 1), '|', '') as crew_name,
       replace(regexp_substr(replace(address, '/ ', '|'), '[^|]*[|]', 1, 2), '|', '') as city,
       replace(regexp_substr(replace(address, '/ ', '|'), '[^|]*[|]', 1, 3), '|', '') as person_name,
       replace(regexp_substr(replace(address, '/ ', '|'), '[^|]*[|]', 1, 4), '|', '') as owner
from (select 'ESS GEE ELECTRO/SOLUTIONS PVT. LT /  noida / BIJENDRA SINGH / . / 9999077027 / 784261 / 2000027697' as address from dual union all
      select '/ delhi / BIJENDRA SINGH / NAKI RAM / 9891884813 / 784262 / 2000057282' as address from dual union all
      select 'ELECTRO PVT. LT/  punjab / w/o birbal SINGH /  / 9310202020 / 784270 / 2000080264' as address from dual
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ad24439b5ff40b01243cfca2bf5459a) is a db<>fiddle.